# How to query Installed Packages Name and AppExchange Ready columns

Tags: package, publisher, installedpackage

How do I get the installed packages "Name" and "AppExchange Ready"?

PackageLicence and Publisher objects are not providing the above information. Can anyone please suggest in what way I can retrieve those details?

[image: Installed Packages]

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below Query with Tooling API enabled -

```
SELECT Id, SubscriberPackageId, SubscriberPackage.NamespacePrefix,
      SubscriberPackage.Name, SubscriberPackageVersion.Id,
      SubscriberPackageVersion.Name, SubscriberPackageVersion.MajorVersion,
      SubscriberPackageVersion.MinorVersion,
      SubscriberPackageVersion.PatchVersion,
      SubscriberPackageVersion.BuildNumber,
      SubscriberPackageVersion.IsSecurityReviewed
   FROM InstalledSubscriberPackage
   ORDER BY SubscriberPackageId
```

Field from the documentation -

> IsSecurityReviewed - Specifies whether the package has passed the
> security review required for publishing in AppExchange.

**Reference** -

1. InstalledSubscriberPackage object -
   https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_installedsubscriberpackage.htm
2. SubscriberPackageVersion - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_subscriberpackageversion.htm

Comment: I have tried your suggestion with Tooling API. When I try this with HTTP callout, I am getting "Read timed out" Callout Exception. This is the request I made: /services/data/v49.0/tooling/query/?q=Select+SubscriberPackage.NamespacePrefix,SubscriberPackage.Name,SubscriberPackageVersion.IsSecurityReviewed+FROM+InstalledSubscriberPackage

Comment: how much timout you have given

Comment: this is heavy call requires extra time.

Comment: I have set req.setTimeout(120000), and it seems to be the issue has been resolved.